# Google Playstore publishing - which use case to choose for OTP auto-read?

Tags: android, google-play

With the recent policy update, Google is expecting the use case to be selected for read SMS permision. In our app, we need read SMS permission to auto-read OTP at time of registration. Much similar to how Google Pay (Tez) app does.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user&hl=en_IN

Please let me know which use case should I highlight for this ? I could not find the right one from the list that was provided. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should use [Google SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)

Comment: Thank you. I missed this link initially and so posted this question. Thanks for adding it here.

Answer (score 0):

By using SMS Retriever API you can avoid the  READ_SMS permission.
Please refer https://android.jlelse.eu/googles-sms-retriever-api-6540eb3c8e9c

Comment: Thank you. I missed this link initially and so posted this question. Thanks for adding it here.